# Magento 2 - Removed Required From Last name on Checkout Page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, form-validation, checkout-page

How to remove last name required validation from checkout page ?

Answer (score 0):

We can remove last name required validation from checkout page using plugin :-

**1- Define plugin :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Plugin_Remove_Checkout_Lastname_Validation" sortOrder="10" type="Wakar\RemoveCheckoutLastname\Plugin\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**2-Plugin class :-**

```
<?php


namespace Wakar\RemoveCheckoutLastname\Plugin\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend;

class AbstractBackend
{
    public function beforeValidate(
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend $subject,
        $object
    ) {
            $attribute = $subject->getAttribute();
            $attrCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();

            if ($attrCode == 'lastname') {
                $attribute->setIsRequired(0);
            }
    }
}
```